# Does C++ have good libraries to accelerate Windows Forms like software?

Tags: c++, libraries

Suppose you have to develop a software to access customer database, let's say for example "SQL Server".

Are there good libraries to accelerate this job in order to give to my client a good UI?

For example, I could show a grid where he can select his desired customer for updating and deleting existing customers data, also offer a blank form for inputing new customer data?

Thank you

Comment: The title of your post implies you believe the Windows Forms library cannot be used with C++, which is wrong. Or didn't I get you correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/).

With Qt Quick (sometimes known as QML) you get a system to develop GUIs with barely any C++ code - a little like XAML, but lots better as you can embed it into the traditional Qt forms.

[Ars has a little article](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2010/10/canonical-cto-contemplates-qt-we-think-it-has-a-lot-to-offer-ubuntu.ars) and tutorial about writing Qt software, don;t worry about the 'Ubuntu' part, Qt is *very* cross platform.

Comment: And with QT's SQL model classes, you can build a database frontend extremely quickly. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/sql-model.html